# Errors whilst installing kolab

Tags: linux, security, web-server, installation, selinux

i'm struggling for the past 2 days please help me anyone...

```
[root@mail /]# setup-kolab

Please supply a password for the LDAP administrator user 'admin', used to login
to the graphical console of 389 Directory server.

Administrator password [Password]: 

Confirm Administrator password: 

Please supply a password for the LDAP Directory Manager user, which is the
administrator user you will be using to at least initially log in to the Web
Admin, and that Kolab uses to perform administrative tasks.

Directory Manager password [Password]: 

Confirm Directory Manager password: 

Please choose the system user and group the service should use to run under.
These should be existing, unprivileged, local system POSIX accounts with no
shell.

User [nobody]: username

Group [nobody]: username

This setup procedure plans to set up Kolab Groupware for the following domain
name space. This domain name is obtained from the reverse DNS entry on your
network interface. Please confirm this is the appropriate domain name space.

its.com [Y/n]: y

The standard root dn we composed for you follows. Please confirm this is the root
dn you wish to use.

dc=its,dc=com [Y/n]: y

Setup is now going to set up the 389 Directory Server. This may take a little
while (during which period there is no output and no progress indication).

Shutting down dirsrv: 
    admin...                                               [  OK  ]
    example...                                             [  OK  ]
    innovace... server already stopped                     [FAILED]
    kolab...                                               [  OK  ]
    ldap...                                                [  OK  ]
    ldap1... server already stopped                        [FAILED]
    mail... server already stopped                         [FAILED]
*** Error: 3 instance(s) unsuccessfully stopped          [FAILED]

Starting dirsrv: 
    admin...                                               [  OK  ]
    example...                                             [  OK  ]
    innovace...                                            [  OK  ]
    kolab...                                               [  OK  ]
    ldap...                                                [  OK  ]
    ldap1...                                               [  OK  ]
    mail...
[31/May/2013:10:53:36 +051800] createprlistensockets - PR_Bind() on All Interfaces port 389 failed: Netscape Portable Runtime error -5982 (Local Network address is in use.)                                                    [FAILED]
  *** Error: 1 instance(s) failed to start

Please supply a Cyrus Administrator password. This password is used by Kolab to
execute administrative tasks in Cyrus IMAP. You may also need the password
yourself to troubleshoot Cyrus IMAP and/or perform other administrative tasks
against Cyrus IMAP directly.

Cyrus Administrator password [Password]: 
Confirm Cyrus Administrator password: 

Please supply a Kolab Service account password. This account is used by various
services such as Postfix, and Roundcube, as anonymous binds to the LDAP server
will not be allowed.

Kolab Service password [Password]: 
Confirm Kolab Service password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/setup-kolab", line 42, in <module>
    setup.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pykolab/setup/__init__.py", line 43, in run
    components.execute('_'.join(to_execute))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pykolab/setup/components.py", line 170, in execute
    execute(component)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pykolab/setup/components.py", line 202, in   execute
    components[component_name]['function'](conf.cli_args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pykolab/setup/setup_ldap.py", line 405, in execute auth._auth.ldap.add_s(dn, ldif)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 195, in add_s
    return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 458, in result
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid = self.result2(msgid,all,timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 462, in result2
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid, resp_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all,timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 469, in result3
    resp_ctrl_classes=resp_ctrl_classes
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 476, in result4
    ldap_result =     self._ldap_call(self._l.result4,msgid,all,timeout,add_ctrls,add_intermediates,add_extop)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 99, in _ldap_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: {'info': "Insufficient 'add' privilege to the    'userPassword'     attribute", 'desc': 'Insufficient access'}
```

Comment: Give us at least the operating system you are running this into. Why do you think this is SELinux related? Show some AVC denials.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Problem occured when using a password with a % in it on initial installation.
when I redid the setup it was already jacked and gave the error above.
yum removing all kolab packages, then deleting /etc/dirsrv got rid of the bad install.
Then a fresh yum install kolab and setup-kolab fixed it.

Comment: I was using Centos 6.4

Comment: Replace with whatever package manager you happen to be using.